# Calling C++ dll method in C#

Tags: c#, c++

I'm trying to call C++ DLL Method in C#, I have successfully called a few methods before but below method alway failed and i have no idea about this:

**C++**
This description from manual document:

Method header:

```
BOOL SxuptpEnumDevices ( 
    DWORD dwIpaddr,      /* Device server IP address*/  
    LPVOID lpbDevices,   /* Array address of the structure */  
    DWORD cbBuf,         /* Number of bytes of array */ 
    LPDWORD lpdwReaded,  /* Parameter address to which the number of byte copied will be returned */ 
    LPDWORD lpdwReturned /* Parameter address to which the number of structure copied will be returned */ );
```

Method desciption:

**dwIpaddr**: Specify IP address of the device server of which the USB device will be listed.

**lpbDevices**: Pointer indicating the array of SXUSBDEVICE structure. It receives the USB device list.

**cbBuf**: Specifies the size, by byte, of array pointed by lpbDevices.

**lpdwReaded**: Indicates the number of byte copied to lpbDevices.

**lpdwReturned**: Pointer indicating the parameter to which the number of USB devices listed is returned.

*Return value:
TRUE is returned when the function is successfully completed or else FALSE is returned.

Note:

```
typedef struct _SXUSBDEVICE { 
   char szPortName[32];   /* USB logical port name */
   char szDeviceName[64]; /* Device Name */
   DWORD dwIpPc;          /* IP address of connected PC */
   WORD wStatus;          /* Status information */
   WORD wVid;             /* Device VID */
   WORD wPid;             /* Device PID */
   char szLocation[16];   /* USB port info which the device is connected to */
   WORD wClass;           /* USB Interface Class */
} SXUSBDEVICE, *LPSXUSBDEVICE;
```

Called in C++:

```
BOOL result = SxuptpEnumDeviceServers(NULL, 0, &lpbDevices, (sizeof(SXPSERVER) * MAX_PSERVER), &dwReaded, &dwReturned);
if(result){
     //dwReturned = 1
     //lpbDevices[dwReturned - 1] will have value
}
```

**C#**

Method header

```
[DllImport(@"Sxuptp.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "SxuptpEnumDevices")]
public static extern bool SxuptpEnumDevices(
   uint dwIpaddr, 
   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 0)] SXPSERVER[] lpbDevices,
   uint cbBuf,
   ref uint lpdwReaded,
   ref uint lpdwReturned);
```

Note:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public struct SXUSBDEVICE
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
        public char[] szPortName; // USB logical port name

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 64)]
        public char[] szDeviceName; // Device Name

        public uint dwIpPc; // IP address of connected PC
        public ushort wStatus; // Status information
        public ushort wVid; // Device VID
        public ushort wPid; // Device PID

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
        public char[] szLocation; // USB port info which the device is connected to
        public ushort wClass; // USB Interface Class
    }
```

**Use method in my project:**

```
//Get all devices in USB Device Server from IP
int MAX_DEVICES = 64; 
uint dwIpaddr = (uint)IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder((int)IPAddress.Parse("169.254.95.193").Address); 
SXUSBDEVICE[] lpbDevices = new SXUSBDEVICE[MAX_DEVICES]; 
uint lpdwReaded = 0, 
lpdwReturned = 0, 
cbuf = (uint)(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(SXUSBDEVICE)) * MAX_DEVICES); 

if (Driver.Sxuptp.SxuptpEnumDevices(dwIpaddr, lpbDevices, cbuf, ref lpdwReaded, ref lpdwReturned))
{
     MessageBox.Show($"lpdwReaded: {lpdwReaded}, lpdwReturned: {lpdwReturned}");
}
else
{
     MessageBox.Show("Error");
}
```

This method is alway return false and i think some C# code has some mistake in somewhere but i have no idea about that. Please teach me or remind me anything to fix it !

Comment: Have you some debug symbols for that C++ DLL? That way you could debug into the actual method call and see what's happening, i.e. verify passed arguments / struct.

Comment: @Chilipp  i just only have a DLL and manual document which description method like above. I think some think problem with "LPVOID lpbDevices" because i detect some sample code to use in C++ like this: SxuptpEnumDevices(dwIpaddr, &lpbDevices, (sizeof(SXUSBDEVICE) * MAX_DEVICE), &dwReaded, &dwReturned)

Comment: `SizeParamIndex = 0` looks wrong. This would mean that `dwIpaddr` holds the number of elements in the array. Also why do you specify `Pack = 1`. I can't see any alignment changes on the C struct.

Comment: @Timo i am tried with no "SizeParamIndex = 0" and only attribute "LayoutKind.Sequential" in struct but no luck. If method run sucessfully, lpbDevices array will have lpdwReturned (number of) items

Comment: @pantan Is it necessary to use `EntryPoint = "SxuptpEnumDevices"` What will happen if this is removed ?

Comment: @control EntryPoint will make sure my method access exactly method name of DLL, if DLL have no any SxuptpEnumDevices method, It will throw exception to warning about that

Comment: Are you sure `Pack = 1` is correct, C++ usually does 32-bit packing